# setting self as createby

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

A user can either register themselves or can be created by another user.  When a user is created, the CreateBy is set to the user who created the new user.  When the user registers, we want to set the CreateBy to the user who is registering.

```
public class User
{
    int Id;
    string Username;
    User CreateBy;
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x=>x.Id);
        Map(x=>x.Usernam);
        References(x=>x.CreateBy)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Not.LazyLoad();
     }
}
```

If the db field 'CreateBy' is set to `not null`, how do we set the CreateBy to the user who is trying to register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class User : Auditable
{
    int Id;
    string Username;
}

public class Auditable :  IAuditable
{
    public virtual int CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class AuditEventListener : IPreInsertEventListener
{
    public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent @event)
    {
        var audit = @event.Entity as IAuditable;
        if (audit == null)
            return false;

       var userId = [Your-current-user].Current().UserId; 
       Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "CreatedBy", userId); 
       audit.CreatedBy= userId;    
       return false;
   }

   private void Set(IEntityPersister persister, object[] state, string propertyName, object value)
   {
       var index = Array.IndexOf(persister.PropertyNames, propertyName);
       if (index == -1)
           return;
       state[index] = value;
   }
}

.Mappings(...)
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.EventListeners.PreInsertEventListeners = new IPreInsertEventListener[] { new Convention.AuditEventListener() })
.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Nice one. If we would think about `IPreInsertEventListener` as AOP filter... that makes sense. *Just wanted to add: I rather apply AOP on Business layer than Data layer*